# iOS Safari using wrong domain for relative CSS path

Tags: ios, css, safari

I'm using [Font Awesome](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) from a CDN:

```
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
>
```

On desktop browsers, it works all fine. But on iOS Safari browsers (iOS 9), the icons do not render, and are all replaced by a square.

I connected my iPad to a Mac, launched developer tools, and noticed that the iOS browser attempts to download the font files from my own server, instead of the CDN.

For example, the CSS file on the CDN contains the following line:

```css
@font-face{
    src:url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.4.0');
```

But iOS Safari resolves it to:

```
GET http://mywebsite.com/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.4.0
```

As far as I know, in CSS, relative paths are relative to the location of the CSS file, not to the location of the current page.

Is this a (known?) bug in iOS Safari? Is there a fix?

Any pointer appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure exactly where the problem was, but upgrading to iOS 9.2 and Font Awesome 4.5.0 seems to have fixed the problem for me.

I still had an issue though, as the icons appeared for a second and then disappeared. It turned out this was because of an outdated [viewport-units-buggyfill.js](https://github.com/rodneyrehm/viewport-units-buggyfill) script. Upgrading it to 0.5.5 fixed this other problem.

Comment: I had this issue with viewport-units-buggyfill, too - though just upgrading didn't fix it (I was on the latest 0.6.0 at the time of writing). The issue is that viewport-units-buggyfill needs to move the context of the stylesheet to the local document, which makes the relative paths relative to the document. Add the attribute `data-viewport-units-buggyfill="ignore"` to the font-awesome style element to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with a http in front of the URL, like this?

```
<link rel="stylesheet"
href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Comment: This should not matter, as it just uses `http` or `https` depending on the current page. And this is the [recommended way](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/get-started/) to use it.